# isSubstring recursive method

Tags: java, methods, recursion, substring

Here's the code that calls the recursive method:

```
if (isSubstring(str1, str2))
    System.out.println ("\"" + str1 + "\" is a substring of " +
                        "\"" + str2 + "\"");
else
    System.out.println ("\"" + str1 + "\" is not a substring of " + 
                       "\"" + str2 + "\"");
```

This is the method I've completed so far, it is almost working:

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String str, String target)
{   
    if (target.length() == 0)
        return false;

    if (str.equals(target))
        return true;

    else     
        return (isSubstring(str, target.substring(0,target.length()-1)));            
}
```

So it works if str1 is passed as "zzz" and str2 is passed as "zzzabcdef", then it will return true. However it does not return true if str2 would be "abczzzxx" or "abczzz". Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Your method could be a one line thing: `return str.contains(target);`

Comment: I noticed your `if (target.length() == 0)` statement. You might want to put in some null checks for str and target as well. I like to use the `StringUtils.isBlank()` method; See http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)

Comment: @assylias I guess the point is doing it with recursion as an exercise

Comment: @maasg Possibly - the OP should have made it clear. If the goal was simply to reimplement contains, a look at the source could be instructive too.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - basically your recursive method is always just taking off the final character, then recursing, until either it's got an empty string or the value is *equal* to the first string.

That means the only *possible* place it can find the first string is at the start of the target string, which means it's really a `startsWith` method.

One option which would be horrifically inefficient but which I believe should work would be to try taking a character off the front *and* try to take a character off the end (independently):

```
return isSubstring(str, target.substring(0, target.length() - 1))
    || isSubstring(str, target.substring(1));
```

Comment: @maasg: I suspect so... it's certainly ghastly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String str, String target) {
            System.out.println("target :" + target);
            if (str.equals(target))
                return true;
            else if (str.length() > target.length())
                return false;
            else
                return (isSubstring(str, target.substring(1, target.length())))
                        || (isSubstring(str,
                                target.substring(0, target.length() - 1)));
        }
```

This should recursively try out all the sub-strings from target.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you only drop characters from the end of the string. Your function could be correctly called `startsWith(...)`

For substring match, I'd try the following algo:

Drop characters from the main string while there's no match.
Starting consuming both strings when they match until you match all consecutive characters of the substring, or until you find a non-matching char, which will allow you to stop earlier.

Something like this:

```
boolean isSubString(String s1, String s, boolean match) {
   if (s1 == "") return true; 
   if (s == "") return false;
   if ((s1.charAt(0) != s.charAt(0)) && match) return false; //failfast
   if (s1.charAt(0) == s.charAt(0)) return isSubString(s1.substring(1), s.substring(1), true);
   return isSubString(s1.substring(1), s.substring(1), match);
}

boolean isSubString(String s1, String s) {
    return isSubString(s1, s,false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a challenge to write this kind of function only with charAt(), length() and substring(), here is what I wrote and I think it is working fine...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(isSubstring("pgram", "program")); // Expected: false
    System.out.println(isSubstring("string", "substring")); // Expected: true
    System.out.println(isSubstring("zzz", "zzzabcdef")); // Expected: true
    System.out.println(isSubstring("zzz", "abczzzxx")); // Expected: true
    System.out.println(isSubstring("zzz", "abczzz")); // Expected: true
    System.out.println(isSubstring("hell", "hello")); // Expected: true
    System.out.println(isSubstring("ada", "Madam")); // Expected: true
}

public static boolean isSubstring(String str, String target)
{
    if (str.length() == 0)
        return true;

    if (target.length() == 0)
        return false;

    if (str.charAt(0) == target.charAt(0)) // "zzz", "zzzabcdef"
    {
        if (str.length() == target.length()) // "zzz", "zzz"
            return isSubstring(str.substring(1), target.substring(1));

        else if (target.length() > str.length()) // "zzz", "zzzabcdef"
        {
            boolean r1 = isSubstring(str, target.substring(0, str.length())); // "zzz", "zzzabcdef"
            boolean r2 = isSubstring(str, target.substring(1)); // Or maybe "string", "substring"

            return r1 || r2;
        }
    }

    return isSubstring(str, target.substring(1));
}
```